# What's up with "Error in lockf()" just for one particular user?

Tags: solaris, serial-port

We're running a Java manufacturing/equipment control application on Solaris.  Equipment control is done via the serial port on the SunRay terminal at the user station.  The interesting thing is that it fails for one particular user.  He can go to any machine and have it fail.  Works fine for all other users on all machines.  The errors returned are:

```
Error opening "/tmp/SUNWut/sessions/7/unit/dev/term/a"
Error in lockf()
```

Nothing special about this user account.  .profile matches everyone else.  Any ideas on what might be broken about this one specific user account that would prevent him from being able to open the serial port?

Comment: Does the output of `groups` for that user match that of other users?

Comment: Yes, the groups output does match.

Comment: Can you run `truss` on the process and see which system call gets an error just before the program prints the error message? Also, could you post the relevant snippet of source code if possible?

Comment: The exception comes back from inside the Sun SerialComm package during a request to open serial port a.

Comment: Can you tell what error `open()` is returning? EPERM, EACCES, EMFILE, ENOENT, EAGAIN?

Comment: Well, I'm working on it, but it's a challenge.  I don't have a Sunray at my location (so I can't run the app in the same mode as that user for myself) and the site in question is on the opposite side of the continent, so I can't just drive over and check it out.  The guys out there don't know anything about computers either, so I've had a terrible time getting info out of them.  This is turning into quite the adventure.  :-)

Comment: Check that the particular user's CLASSPATH is the same as the others'.